# Multiline mx:Text truncation

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

Is there a way to truncate multiline text with ... within a mx:Text control. It has the truncateToFit property but that doesn't seem to work.

```
<mx:Text id="txt_Description" text="{data.Description}" width="100%" height="70" truncateToFit="true" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are several issues with truncateToFit and some components or with html text :

There are some workarounds here :

http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Get_truncateToFit_for_htmlText_with_and_without_te-16580.html
http://cookbooks.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=showdetails&postId=13306